# dnf has lost track of an installed package

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, rpm, dnf

Despite that `vim` is installed on my Fedora 29 system, the command

```
dnf search vim-common
```

returns "No matches found."  In contrast, the command

```
rpm -qa vim-common
```

returns the name of the installed RPM file.

I have tried `dnf --refresh update`, to no avail.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is 'going on' but you could try clearing the problem with:

```
rpm -e vim-common
```

and then:

```
dnf install vim-common
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `dnf install vim-common` also says "no match".

Comment: Was the 'rpm -e' command successful in removing the package? You might have needed '--nodeps'. You might also try 'rpmdb --rebuild'

Comment: Yes, I first removed the dependencies `R-core` and `meson`/`ninja`.  I was able to use `dnf remove` to remove these dependencies, which I will install again later.  Then I used `rpm -e` to remove `vim-common`, `vim-enhanced`, and a half dozen other `vim-*` packages that `rpm` knew about.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `rpmdb --rebuilddb` command did not solve the problem with `dnf`.  Is there an analogous `dnf` command?  I already tried `dnf reinstall dnf`.

Comment: Nothing on the man page AFAICS. You could try 'dnf clean all'.

Comment: I did try that, but `dnf` still doesn't think `vim` exists.  Thanks for your effort and interest, @wef, but I guess this problem is not worthwhile solving.  I've sidestepped it by downloading and installing the necessary RPMs.

Answer (score 0):

'dnf search` looks in metadata - i.e. it downloads repofiles from remote repositories and then downloads it to its own cache and search there. DNF does not search in rpmdb.

rpm search only in rpmdb

In your case, DNF is likely unable to download information from remote repositories.

Comment: You're right, the `dnf` and `rpm` metadata caches are separate.  But `dnf` also knows what packages are installed, as does `rpm`.  I don't understand why `dnf` says that `vim` is not installed when `rpm` says it is (and indeed it is).

Comment: DNF is aware of installed package (e.g. for dnf remove) but dnf search is searching only in metadata.